# How to pass value to an exe and then the next button should be executed by powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have the code below which executes an exe file and then i want the path which is assigned to a variable to be copied into the text box of that exe and once it gets copied then the next button in the exe should get clicked\executed automatically by powershell.

```
& "D:\SOFTWARE\notepad ++.exe"
$Path="C:\Program Files"
```

Basically i will be using this code for some other exe file but process would be same. So is there any way by which i can do this by using powershell?

[image: Consider an example of an image below]

Consider the snapshot below of the UI of application installed. If i want to pass the product key which i have declared in a variable inside the powershell after passing it to the application and then i want its Get Product Details button to be hit\Run.
[image: Snapshot of application UI where i want value to be copied and button to be executed]

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is pass the variables into the msi by running it quietly without UI. Try the following first (assuming your exe is actually just an MSI wrapper)

`msiexec.exe /i $PathToExe /q /l*vx log.txt`

This should quietly launch the msi and produce a log.txt file. Wait a few moments for it to complete since it is installing in the background. Then check if it correctly installed. Then check the log file to see all the variables that were set at the end. Guessing by their names or values, you could then pass them in the next time simply by adding `variablename=variablevalue` to the command line call. You might need to experiment and learn a bit about MSI and msiexec as part of this.

If talk about invoking UI actions in general, then you would need to look at the `AutomationElement` class but it can get very complex here on...

Comment: Hi bergmeister, Actually what i want is after the exe or msi is installed then how can i pass a value to it inside its textbox by powershell and hit its button. so that it gives me the result.

Comment: OK. The way you described the main question is very confusing... But anyway: Is that exe your own application? If so then you should rather think about exposing some sort of API using e.g. WCF. If not then you need to use the MS UI Automation framework. An example using it via PowerShell can be found here: https://gist.github.com/xiongjia/6749035

Comment: So i'm really confused. It looks like you are asking to auto-fill the GUI and the installation process. Is there any particular reason why you won't use the command-line features? Have you looked into them first?

In my opinion you are over complicating things abit. Howerever, if you truly want to go this route, i believe (AutoHotkey)[https://autohotkey.com/] would be your best bet. It's like SendKeys but way way way better.

This will let you automate what you want to accomplish. But again, if i were you, i"d look into writing a script instead of scripting the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using SendKeys.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/10/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/